# How to use boolean assignment in ternary operator if optional prop is an array in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to derive an object property based on whether an optional prop is an array.

I have this assignment:

```js
const isRequestingMultipleDevices = Array.isArray(deviceIds);
```

Then this object:

```js
    {
      data: isRequestingMultipleDevices
        ? deviceIds.map((deviceId) => getData(deviceId)) // Object is possibly 'undefined'
        : (deviceIds && [getData(deviceIds)]) || [], // Object is possibly 'undefined'
    };
```

It complains because `deviceIds` is optional. However, this is fine:

```js
    {
      data: Array.isArray(deviceIds)
        ? deviceIds.map((deviceId) => getData(deviceId))
        : (deviceIds && [getData(deviceIds)]) || [],
    };
```

I want to use `isRequestingMultipleDevices` because I need it in multiple places.

How do I define the boolean once and use it everywhere? TIA

Comment: Could you show us the error ? I've created a snippet but can't recall [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwG4EtgIJJwjAvDAbQEYB2AGhiIA4KiBOCgJgAYBdAbgChPRJYUIAJQQBHAK4JoKMAHMAsmIA2UFAAdFCACLI0kvDACCAJyMBDAJ4A6AcbPmAFIlTosEAJRdOAMzFhgK8BgZBChNUyhTexQ4AC4YMDEAWwAjBCMAHwSUtIJWNzjfRC9pBDgYdPik1KMYAG9OGEaYIxCxIzAYQoRisFKuAF9uXmgYEGSAK316pqa4cNM4qKFRCSlZBWU1DW1nSQaZpoB+eB0XbEtE01V7R1PMODc8AD4gkLCI292sNzd9g5hFk5dK4YAAyUGEYKheafYHYNx5R7pCq5MicfrsIA)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT sure: `'(parameter) deviceIds: string | string[] | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a disclaimer, I must confess that I haven't been able to provoke the exact same error you report, but I believe the problem is due to us knowing more about the situation than the type checker. What I mean is this:

After this assignment

```
const isRequestingMultipleDevices = Array.isArray(deviceIds);
```

we know the following: if `isRequestingMultipleDevices` is `true`, then `deviceIds` is *both* defined and an `Array`. If it's `false`, then it might be undefined, and it's certainly not an array.

Later on, when it comes time to *use* `isRequestingMultipleDevices`,

```
{
  data: isRequestingMultipleDevices
  ? deviceIds.map((deviceId) => getData(deviceId))
  : (deviceIds && [getData(deviceIds)]) || [],
};
```

even though *we* are certain that `deviceIds` is both defined and an `Array` in the first arm of the ternary expression, the type checker has apparently not been able to narrow the type in the same way (there may be several reasons for this). For this reason, it rejects your calls to `deviceIds.map`. The rejection of `getData(deviceIds)` happens for an analagous reason.

In the second case, when you "inlined" the array check, the type checker was able to infer that `deviceIds` is an `Array` in the first arm, and not an `Array` in the second, and thus it accepts the entire expression.

One way to resolve this is to include ["type assertions"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) for `deviceIds` at both call sites:

```
// Assuming the device ID(s) are strings:
{
  data: isRequestingMultipleDevices
  ? (deviceIds as string[]).map((deviceId) => getData(deviceId))
  : (deviceIds && [getData(deviceIds as string)]) || [],
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer - understood - it's working!